# Can NetworkX library read RDF data in Ntriple format and build a Graph object along with attributes or node features

Tags: graph, rdf, networkx, rdflib, n-triples

Can NetworkX library read RDF data in Ntriple format and build a Graph object along with attributes or node features.
I tried the below code to convert the RDF data(.nt file) in to Graph using the rdflib,

```
from rdflib.extras.external_graph_libs import *
from rdflib import Graph, URIRef, Literal
import networkx as nx

graph = Graph()
graph.parse(“Airports-with-lables.nt”, format=“nt”)
nx_graph = rdflib_to_networkx_multidigraph(graph)
nx.write_graphml(nx_graph,“example_airport.graphml”)
```

However the generated grahml file doesn’t have attributes, because of which I am not able to proceed with StellarGraph Hinsage algorithm(https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph/tree/develop/demos/node-classification/hinsage) which expects the node features as one of the parameter.

Can anyone help on this please.

Comment: the method does exactly what it's supposed to do, subjects and objects are the later nodes of the `MultiDiGraph`, predicates are used as edge keys (to identify multi-edges).